# ffmpeg no cutting accurately

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a Python script that shows the chapters of an M4V video and gives the user the option to extract this chapters.

The problem is that `ffmpeg` is not cutting accurately. It cuts a little before the start time given and/or a little after the end time.

If you guys want to test, download this video:

http://download.jw.org/files/media_books/7b/bh_LSB_01_r240P.m4v

This is the command I am sending:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:37:32.52 -t 00:00:10.244 -i "videos\bh_LSB_01_r240P.m4v" -vcodec copy "out\19_Salmos\90\002.m4v"
```

Even though it cuts right in the beginning (by complete luck), it cuts after the end time.

I was told that I need to re-encode the video and use the options force-keyframe and segment_time, but segment_time is not even recognized as an option. And what encoding should I use?

Answer (score 1):

While using -vcodec copy, it must cut at the nearest keyframe. To get frame accurate you must reencode the video.

Comment: what encoding you reccomend?

Comment: I recommend h.264. `-vcodec libx264`

Comment: should I encode the video and then cut it or can I encode and cut in the same command? and what is the extension?

Comment: Every time you encode, you lose a little quality, so you always want to minimize the number of times you re-encode. Extension is a container feature, not codec. the m4v container will support h.264, but so does many others.

Comment: I tried encoding the original video with h.264 but it is giving the error: "Codec type mismatch for mapping #0.0 -> #0.0"

Comment: That is a different problem. You should open another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24507/discussion-between-filipe-teixeira-and-szatmary).